# Grey blank screen with various vnc services from Windows 7 to Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: linux, remote-access, ubuntu-14.04, vnc

So, I have been attempting to access my work computer (Ubuntu 14.04) from home (windows 7).

I am using vnc and I have tried both tightvnc, xrdp, and default vino services on work computer.

Here is what I found not working and working.

Tightvnc server/xrdp server (linux) + tightvnc viewer (windows): NOT WORKING
Result: grey blank screen with X cursor
Attempted diagnosis: gnome-fallback, x-windows, gdm, all variations of xstartup files I could find online. Didn't find a solution

Vino server (linux) + tightvnc viewer (windows): WORKING if encryption disabled
Very straight forward setup through Desktop Sharing
Result: No matching security types! from tightvnc viewer connection
Solution: gsettings set org.gnome.Vino require-encryption false

Tightvnc server/Vino server (linux) + Remote Desktop (windows): NOT WORKING
Result: grey blank screen with X cursor (regardless of the vino security session)

So, I now have one solution that works but I don't feel secured with the encryption turned off. And I am really curious why I always get grey screen. Is it a security matching problem, or display problem? And are vino server and tightvnc server or other vnc server using the same  ubuntu system service? Or these vnc services are independent of each other?

Thanks!

Comment: X11vnc allows you to export your running desktop session with SSL encryption/authentication. Alternatively, to fix blank screen, try installing another desktop environment, e.g. xfce, and [modifying xstartup](https://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2131958.html) or /etc/xrdp/startwm.sh to start the environment instead of Gnome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the grey blank screen problem, try to use xfce4 desktop environment, install it by:

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4
```

And then create an xfce session

```
sudo gedit ~/.xsession
```

Where place only one line *xfce4-session*

Then reboot your linux machine and try to access it remotely again.

Comment: Hey Nikolay, thanks for the comment. I have tried this method and it doesn't work. I guess this issue is very system specific and a little tweak in either system would cause problems. But anyway, thank you!

Comment: In my case it worked. To change from the grey screen to the command line, one may use CTRL + ALT + F1